# Firebase SwiftUI - Create document with subcollection

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am trying to add a comment's feature to my app. When a user creates a post, I am trying to also add a sub-collection to that post names "comments". However, with the code I have, I simply can not figure out how to create this sub-collection. Preferably, I would like to create this sub-collection with no documents inside by default, however I've read that thats not possible.

```
if img_Data.count == 0{
            
            ref.collection("Posts").document().setData([
                "title" : self.postTxt,
                "url": "",
                "ref": ref.collection("Users").document(self.uid),
                "time": Date(),
                "likes": 0,
                "likedBy": FieldValue.arrayUnion([])
            ])
            ref.collection("Posts").document().collection("comments").document().setData([ //this is where I am trying to create "comments" but it's not working.
                "title": "testing"
            ])
            { (err) in
                
                if err != nil{
                    self.isPosting = false
                    return
                }
                
                self.isPosting = false
                //closing view when posted
                present.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
///else statement for image posting
```

The code above does not create a sub-collection with the new post.

I BELIEVE my problem is under ".document().collection("comments"). I don't have anything inside the (), so it's unsure what document to add the sub-collection to. In my other files, I've simply referenced "id" for a specific document, but I am not sure how to do that since I am creating the document as-well as then modifying it.

If there is a better way to do this, please let me know. This is what I came up with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `document()` on a collection reference, it returns a new document reference. If you capture that reference in a variable, you can create the new subcollection under *that* specific document.

So:

```
let newDocRef = ref.collection("Posts").document()     //  Capture new document reference
newDocRef.setData([                                    //  Create the new document itself
    "title" : self.postTxt,
    "url": "",
    "ref": ref.collection("Users").document(self.uid),
    "time": Date(),
    "likes": 0,
    "likedBy": FieldValue.arrayUnion([])
])
newDocRev.collection("comments").document().setData([  //  Create a document in the subcollection
    "title": "testing"
])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just to build off of this, if I delete the post, the "Comments" sub-collection still stays. How would I be able to delete the sub-collection and all of the documents inside of it if I delete the post? My current delete post code is here.
`func deletePost(id: String){
        
        ref.collection("Posts").document(id).delete { (err) in
            if err != nil{
                print(err!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
        }`
Not sure how to format that correctly, but theres all the code

Comment: That seems like a new question, but you'll need to delete all documents from the subcollection. Once you do that, the subcollection itself also disappears.